# how to retrieve the current user id in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, userid

I am trying to retrieve the id of the current user logged in so i can save it to another table. I've been around stack overflow and found a few ways of doing this but nothing seems to work.

This throws the error: Call to a member function user() on a non-object

```
$this->Auth->user('id');
```

This returns a null value:

```
$this->Session->read('User.id');
```

I played around with this for a bit https://github.com/mcurry/cakephp_static_user but for some reason it complained that I was calling unregistered functions when I know I  had implemented them.

I've tried a few variations of the auth and session lines but they all return null or throw an error. Can anyone shed some light on what I might be missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you had added Session and Auth components in controller

Comment: how do I ensure that I have added them to controller? I've got this line in my appcontroller:

public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar', 'Session', 'DataTable', 'RequestHandler', 'Usermgmt.UserAuth');

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$loggedInUser = AuthComponent::user();
```

This gives the whole user array, if you're just after the id then you need this:

```
$userId = $loggedInUser['User']['id'];
```

It's what I'm using where I need it, and it works well for me.

Comment: You can also pass the key as a parameter, the method will then return that specific field (in case it exists). http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not using CakePHP's built-in Auth component. 
Your code says:

```
$components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar', 'Session', 'DataTable', 'RequestHandler', 'Usermgmt.UserAuth')
```

To include CakePHP's Auth component:

```
$components = array('...', 'Auth')
```